# How to style an svg inside a hyperlink using class?

Tags: html, css

I am styling an "svg" icon in my web application by adding a hover affect to it. I have added the svg in-line in my HTML document. The svg is wrapped inside a hyperlink and I want to add hover affect to the link (not the svg itself). Problem is, when I use a class to style my link it doesn't work but when I use an id, it does work. I can't understand why.

I've been able to style it the way I want with IDs but I want to understand why is not working with classes.

So the problem is actually in the footer. To be certain that the problem isn't that other classes are overwriting my svg hover styling, here is my entire footer in HTML:

```
<footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-2">
                    <ul class="footer-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">iOS App</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Android App</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="col span-1-of-2">
                    <ul class="social-icons">
                        <li><a class="facebook-icon" href="#"><svg version="1.1" width="25px" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                            viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
                            <path d="M384,176h-96v-64c0-17.664,14.336-32,32-32h32V0h-64l0,0c-53.024,0-96,42.976-96,96v80h-64v80h64v256h96V256h64L384,176z"/>
                            </svg></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="vendors/img/social-media/twitter.svg"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="vendors/img/social-media/google-plus.svg"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="vendors/img/social-media/instagram.svg"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <p>
                    Copyright &copy; 2015 by Omnifood. All rights reserved.
                </p>
            </div>
        </footer>
```

and here is my CSS for the footer:

```
/* ----- FOOTER ------ */

footer {
    background-color: #313131;
    padding: 50px;
}

.footer-nav {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}

.social-icons {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
}

.social-icons img {
    width: 25px;
}

.footer-nav li,
.social-icons li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.footer-nav li:last-child,
.social-icons li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.footer-nav li a:link,
.footer-nav li a:visited,
.social-icons li a:link,
.social-icons li a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 0;
    color: #888;
    fill: #888;
    transition: fill 0.2s;
}

.facebook-icon:hover,
.facebook-icon:active{
    fill: #fff;
}

.footer-nav li a:hover,
.footer-nav li a:active {
    color: #ddd;
}

footer p {
    color: #888;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 90%;
    margin-top: 30px;
}


/* ----- END FOOTER ------ */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
.facebook-icon:hover 
.facebook-icon:active{
    fill: #fff;
    color: #ddd;
}
```

you should  either have

```
.facebook-icon:hover #Capa_1
.facebook-icon:active #Capa_1{
    fill: #fff;
    color: #ddd;
}
```

so that the fill and color can actually be applied to the svg element.

this also works with classes!

You just have to applie a class="capa_class" to the svg element,

and then you can do:

```
.facebook-icon:hover .capa_class,
.facebook-icon:active .capa_class{
    fill: #fff;
    color: #ddd;
}
```

and it will work aswell

```css
/* ----- FOOTER ------ */

footer {
    background-color: #313131;
    padding: 50px;
}

.footer-nav {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}

.social-icons {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
}

.social-icons img {
    width: 25px;
}

.footer-nav li,
.social-icons li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.footer-nav li:last-child,
.social-icons li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.footer-nav li a:link,
.footer-nav li a:visited,
.social-icons li a:link,
.social-icons li a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 0;
    color: #888;
    fill: #888;
    transition: fill 0.2s;
}

/*
.facebook-icon:hover #Capa_1,
.facebook-icon:active #Capa_1{
    fill: #fff;
    color: #ddd;
}

*/

.facebook-icon:hover .capa_class,
.facebook-icon:active .capa_class{
    fill: #fff;
    color: #ddd;
}


footer p {
    color: #888;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 90%;
    margin-top: 30px;
}


/* ----- END FOOTER ------ */
```

```html
<footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-2">
                    <ul class="footer-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">iOS App</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Android App</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="col span-1-of-2">
                    <ul class="social-icons">
                        <li><a class="facebook-icon" href="#"><svg version="1.1" width="25px" class="capa_class" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                            viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
                            <path d="M384,176h-96v-64c0-17.664,14.336-32,32-32h32V0h-64l0,0c-53.024,0-96,42.976-96,96v80h-64v80h64v256h96V256h64L384,176z"/>
                            </svg></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="vendors/img/social-media/twitter.svg"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="vendors/img/social-media/google-plus.svg"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="vendors/img/social-media/instagram.svg"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <p>
                    Copyright &copy; 2015 by Omnifood. All rights reserved.
                </p>
            </div>
        </footer>
```

Comment: This method works fine but it works only if the svg is added inline in the HTML document. How could the same functionality be achieved if I want my svg to be in a separate file ?